# Subsetting rows with range of column having same values

Tags: r, subset

In R with a dataframe:

```
     one two three four
  1   A   A    Z   Z
  2   A   A    A   Z
  3   A   A    A   A
  4   Z   A    A   A
  5   A   A    A   A
```

I want to extract the subset whose rows have at least one `Z` in column `two : four`. That is:

```
         one two three four
      1   A   A    Z   Z
      2   A   A    A   Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix (from removing the first column (`df[-1]` and comparing (`==`) with `"Z"`) to extract the rows

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1]=="Z")>0,]
#  one two three four
#1   A   A     Z    Z
#2   A   A     A    Z
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236519/replacing-for-loop-with-foreach-loop/49237000?noredirect=1#comment85479099_49237000) of replacing for loops with foreach loop or parSapply. Thanks.