# Replacing for loop with foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach

I want to parellelize my code so that I can utilize all the cores. Therefore, I want to replace the for loop with foreach loop. As I am begginner to R, I could not understand how diferent posts on this topic address the issue. It will be great if somebody can help me with it in step-by-step manner (posting comments with each line, so that I can understand it). Below is my for loop, that I want to replace with foreach:

```
# A function used for Janshon-Shanon-Divergence computation, that I use inside my nested for loop
JensShanDiver = function(a,b) {
        m = 0.5 * (a + b)
        LRa = ifelse(a > 0, log2(a/m), 0)
        LRb = ifelse(b > 0, log2(b/m), 0)
        JSD = 0.5 * (sum(a * LRa) + sum(b * LRb))
        return(JSD)
}

#an empty dataframe having same dimensions as input dataframe
output <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(input), ncol = ncol(input)))

#a vector of same length as of each row in input dataframe
v2 <- numeric(length(input[1,]))

for (j in 1:nrow(input)){
  #take each row from input df
   v1 <- as.numeric(input[j,])
   for(i in 1:length(v1)){
  # update an index value in the initially defined vector
    v2[i] <- 1
  # Take the sum of both vectors
    ifelse(v1[i] == 0, output_vec <- 1, output_vec <- JensShanDiver(v1, v2))
  # Reset the updated index to 0 again
    v2[i] <- 0
  # write the output value at [j,i]th index in the output dataframe 
    output[j,i] <- output_vec
   }
 }
```

Sample of input dataframe is given below:

```
dput(input)
structure(c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.5, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ranges_in_X51214", 
"ranges_in_X56499", "ranges_in_X6383")))
```

Here is the expected output for the given input:

```
> dput(output)
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 0.311278124459133, 0.311278124459133, 
0, 0.459147917027245, 0.459147917027245, 0.459147917027245, 1, 
1, 0), X2 = c(1, 0.311278124459133, 0.311278124459133, 1, 0.459147917027245, 
0.459147917027245, 0.459147917027245, 0.311278124459133, 0.311278124459133, 
1), X3 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.459147917027245, 0.459147917027245, 
0.459147917027245, 0.311278124459133, 0.311278124459133, 1)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: There is much optimization of your R code that can be done before trying to parallelize it.

Comment: Can you add the desired output please ?

Comment: I agree @F.Privé. Premature optimization and all that.... https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I have updated my output in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first pass which removes the inner loop.
The construction of the `ifelse` statement was incorrect. I also don't understand the purpose of v2<-1 and then v2<-0 two steps later.

```
input<-read.table(header=TRUE, text ="ranges_in_X51214 ranges_in_X56499 ranges_in_X6383
0.0              0.0               1
0.5              0.5               0
0.5              0.5               0")

output <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(input), ncol = ncol(input)))

#a vector of same length as of each row in input dataframe
v2 <- numeric(length(input[1,]))
v2 <- 1
for (j in 1:nrow(input)){
  #take each row from input df
  v1 <- as.numeric(input[j,])
  # Take the sum of both vectors
  output_vec<-ifelse(v1 == 0,  1, sum(v1)+1)
  # write the output value at j row
  output[j,] <- output_vec
}
```

This output matches the output of the original code.  As the comments above say there is additional optimization which can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The purpose of V2 and V1 is to first generate 2 vectors. V1 is the jth row of the input dataframe in every iteration of the loop and V2 is another vector of same length as V1 having only 0 values but at the ith index we will have 1. If you understood my explanation, can you please update your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: One point to mention, I actually don't use the sum function, I have wrote a customized function which computes jansen-shanon-divergence, and for that computation, we need 2 vectors and that computation is done for every index of input's jth vector (done by the inner for loop). To make it easy I used the sum function here so that I do not complicate my post by adding an other outer function.

Comment: The above example shows how to vectorize the `ifelse` function. Sorry, but I can't with vectorizing your custom built function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. I have updated my question with real example (including my custom function) and input/output samples. Please take a look if now it makes sense to you.